# C# :ZXing Variação do primeiro número?

Tags: c#

Gente eu desenvolvi esse leitor de codigo de barras em C# usando o ZXing , ele lê o código de barras de uma img e depois ele pega o número da imagem , move a imagem pra outra pasta e renomeia a imagem com o numero do código de barras

```
            //Esse é o método pra ler a imagem
            Bitmap image;`


            image = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(recebe);

            LuminanceSource source;
            source = new BitmapLuminanceSource(image);
            BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
            Result result = new MultiFormatReader().decodeWithState(bitmap);

            //faz um condicional para ler o que existe dentro da matriz Barcode
            foreach (string code in result)
            {

                if (!Directory.Exists(nomePasta.ToString()))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(nomePasta.ToString());
                }
                else 
                { 

                }

                if (codigo == 0)
                {
                    codigo = Convert.ToInt32(0 + code);

                    File.Move(stringCaminho.ToString(), nomePasta.ToString() + code + ".bmp");
                }

                else if (codigo + 0 > Convert.ToInt32(0 + code))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Código de barras está errado! "+code);
                }

                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(code);
                //esta dando erro para fazer o Move da segunda referencia


                }


                }
```

O problema é que quando ele lê o código de barras ele sempre trás o primeiro número errado, e os outros ele trás certo, o que eu posso fazer?

Comment: Baseado em quê você está dizendo que o primeiro número está errado? Qual o formato identificado (propriedade BarcodeFormat de Result ?

Comment: O código está funcionando . beleza , porém ele não lê o primeiro numero certo . Será erro da dll mesmo ?

Comment: Acho que pode ser problema na biblioteca mesmo. Baixei um leitor pra Windows Phone baseado nessa biblioteca e dá vários resultados aleatórios. É bem inconsistente.